# Why doesn't the limit in polar form imply the existence of the limit

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

First, I'll give my definition of polar coordinates.

Let $f:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. Changing to polar coordinates we get $g:V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},g(r,\theta)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, where $r>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Now my question is, why is this true:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)=L \Rightarrow \lim_{r\to0^+} g(r,\theta)=L $$.

But this isn't:

$$\lim_{r\to0^+} g(r,\theta)=L\Rightarrow\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)=L$$

I've seen various counterexamples of this last statement so I know it is false, however I can't **really** understand why it doesn't work, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because limits for different $\theta$ may not be the same, or, even if they are for any fixed $\theta$, one may be able to find some non-linear curve approaching $0$ along which the limit is different or does not exist.

Comment: It should be useful to see some of your counter example. In general, for a fixed path, we otain always the same limit.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to me that there's a counterexample.  When $r<\varepsilon$, $(x,y)$ is within $\varepsilon$ of $(0,0)$.

Comment: The strongest counterexample I came across is $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$, which by doing polar coordinates, it would equal 0, however it doesn't exist.

Comment: @MatíasSanturio How can you show that it is zero by polar coordinates? Indeed we can’t. We have $$r\frac{\cos^2\theta\sin \theta}{r^2\cos^4 \theta+\sin^2theta}$$ and take the path $$r\cos^2\theta =\sin\theta$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often polar coordinates are useful to handle limits in two variables and when the limit exists we have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x)=L \iff\lim_{(r\to 0^+)} g(r,\theta)=L$$

When limit doesn't exists we can obtain different limits for different paths but along a fixed path we obtain the same limit both in polar and cartesian coordinates.

Comment: So even if $\theta$ is free, we still consider it to be a fixed path? I was under the impression that by using polar coordinates we were considering **every** possible path.

Comment: @MatíasSanturio No we are not. Indeed for any fixed $\theta$ we are simply describing lines but in general we can consider paths with $\theta=\theta(r)$. In principle the limit for a same fixed path will be the same whatever system of coordinates we use to describe the function. In other words the limit can be path dependent but it doesn't depend upon the coordinates used (for a fixed path). When the limit exists any path leads to the same result.