Polar coordinates not to prove that the limit goes to zero
I have to study the differentiability in $(0,0)$ of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x|{y^k}|}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}}$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ with $k\geq0$, and $f(0,0)=0$.
By definition of differentiability, but in in polar coordinates, I have: $\lim_{\rho \to 0}(\rho ^{k-3}\cos\theta|\sin\theta|^{k})$. My question is: this limit is clearly $0$ for $k\gt 3$, because I can say that $(\rho ^{k-3}|\cos\theta||\sin\theta|^{k}) \leq \rho ^{k-3} $. This comes from the fact that therre is a theorem that says that if there is a function $g(\rho)$ such that $|f(x,y)|=|f(\rho\cos\theta, \rho\sin\theta)|\leq g(\rho)$ and $\lim_{\rho \to 0} g(\rho)=0$, then $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)=0$
But can I say that

for $k=3$ the limit is $\cos\theta|\sin\theta|^{k}$ which clearly depends on the direction $\theta$ (and thus doesn’t exist)?
for $k\lt 3$ the limit goes to $\pm\infty$ for (at least) the directions with $|\sin\theta|^k\cos\theta \neq 0$ and thus doesn’t exist?

And if yes, what is it that formally lets me say this? My doubts come from the fact that, $x=\rho\cos\theta, y=\rho\sin\theta$ is a “peculiar” change of coordinates, since the resulting limit is treated as in one variable.
CALCULATIONS
Isn’t it $\rho ^{k-3}$?
$ \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+\rho\cos\theta,y_0+\rho\sin\theta-f(x_0, y_0)-f_x(x_0,y_0)\rho\cos\theta-f_y(x_0, y_0)\rho\sin\theta}{\rho}$ = $\lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{f(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta-f(0, 0)-f_x(0,0)\rho\cos\theta-f_y(0, 0)\rho\sin\theta}{\rho})$ = $\lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{\frac{\rho^{k+1}\cos\theta |\sin\theta |^{k}}{\rho ^3}-0-0\cdot\rho\cos\theta-0\cdot\rho\sin\theta}{\rho})$ = $\lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{\rho^{k+1}\cos\theta |\sin\theta |^{k}}{\rho^4}$

Surely $\rho^{k-3}$ should be $\rho^{k-2}$.

Maybe related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3445915

There is no limitation ti use polar coordinates, sometimes it is convenient covert from cartesian to polar and they are completely equivalent for the limit evaluation.

You need to start by continuity in $(0,0)$ before speaking of differentiability.
First notice that $f(0,y)=0$ for $y\neq 0$ so the only way for $f$ to be continuous in $(0,0)$ is to have $f(0,0)=0$.
In polar coordinates we have $f(x,y)=r^{k-2}\cos(t)|\sin(t)|^k$
Therefore for $k>2$ then $|f(x,y)|\le r^{k-2}\to 0$ so $f$ is continuous in $(0,0)$ in this case.
Now for $k\le 2$ you noticed it depends on $t$, just choose a convenient $t$ and show the limit is $\neq0$.
An easy choice would be $t=\frac\pi 4\iff x=y$.
Indeed $|f(x,x)|=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4|x|^{2-k}}$ which is clearly not going to $0$
i.e. fixed non zero value for $k=2$ and $\infty$ when $k<2$ and you are done.

So we now look at differentiability for $k>2$
$\dfrac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}x=\frac{0-0}x=0\quad$ so $f_x'(0,0)=0$
$\dfrac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}y=\frac{0-0}y=0\quad$ so $f_y'(0,0)=0$
Since both are zero as well as $f(0,0)$, your differentiability ratio expression just simplifies to only :
$\dfrac{f(x,y)}{\Vert(x,y)-(0,0)\Vert_2}=\dfrac{f(x,y)}r=r^{k-3}\cos(t)|\sin(t)|^k$
which is the result you effectively got, and this should go to zero as requested by the definition of differentiability.
For similar reasons as previously you get an easy limit $0$ for $k>3$
Now the case $2<k\le 3$ need to be studied, and you can conclude exactly as previously for a choice of direction $t=\frac\pi 4$ that this is not possible.

Note that to prove the working cases, we use only $r$ so this is not path restricted, $(x,y)$ is always inside a ball $B(0,\delta)$ for some given $\delta$ provided $r<\delta$
..., which is what the definition requires i.e. $\Vert(x,y)-(0,0)\Vert_2<\delta\iff r<\delta$
We use directional limit (i.e. a choice of $t$) only to show counter example that the limit cannot be $0$. So you do not have to worry about the validity, because 1 counter example suffice to infirm a statement.

By the way, thanks for the answer, but I was also asking: is there a theorem that says that I can get to the results directly from the limit in polar coordinates?

$\rho ^3$ comes from $f$ in polar coordinates, but aren’t you missing the $\rho$ in the denominator from the differentiability definition? $ \lim_{\rho\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+\rho\cos\theta,y_0+\rho\sin\theta-f(x_0, y_0)-f_x(x_0,y_0)\rho\cos\theta-f_y(x_0, y_0)\rho\sin\theta}{\boldsymbol\rho}$

I didn't pay attention the question was about differentiability,
But anyway you need continuity FIRST before speaking of differentiability ! Differentiability should only be studied for $k>2$ where there is already continuity.

I modified my answer for differentiability.

My doubts come from the fact that, $x=ρ\cosθ$, $y=ρ\sinθ$
is a “peculiar” change of coordinates, since the resulting limit is treated as in one variable.
No it isn't, indeed for sure we have two varibles also in polar coordinates, notably $\rho$ and $\theta$ which describe the same function.
It is true that for any fixed $\theta$ we are simply describing lines but, in general, we can consider any paths with for example $θ=θ(\rho)$.
The limit for a same fixed path will be the same whatever system of coordinates we use to describe the function.
In other words, the limit can be path dependent but it doesn't depend upon the coordinates used and when the limit exists any path leads to the same result.

thank you very much, this was also very helpful: I thought that the only way to use polar coordinates was by using the sort of “squeeze theorem” i described
